# how to register or add-listener for event of div.onresize for major browsers (IE, firefox and google)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, addeventlistener

how to register or add-listener for event of div.onresize for major browsers (IE, Firefox and chrome)? Onresize event in div tag is not working in Mozilla,Chrome etc. I checked the same code with edit plus software it is working fine.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE> New Document </TITLE>
<META NAME="Generator" CONTENT="EditPlus">
<META NAME="Author" CONTENT="">
<META NAME="Keywords" CONTENT="">
<META NAME="Description" CONTENT="">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var NumOfRow=1;
    var mainDiv;
    var newButton;
    function AddNewItems() {
        var container = document.getElementById ("msgPanel");
        //var message = "The height with padding: " + container.clientHeight + "px.\n";
        var message = "The height with padding and border: " + container.offsetHeight + "px.\n";
        alert(message);
        NumOfRow++;
        mainDiv =document.getElementById('msgPanel');
        newButton=document.createElement('input');
        newButton.type='button';
        newButton.value='NewButton';
        newButton.id='btn'+NumOfRow;
        mainDiv.appendChild(newButton);
    }
    function getParentDivHeight() {
    alert("entered inside");
        var container = document.getElementById ("msgPanel");
        var message = "The height with padding and border onClick event: " + container.offsetHeight + "px.\n";
        var strheight = container.offsetHeight;
        alert("The DIV height in Pixel is :   " + strheight +"px");
    }
    function RemoveNewItems() {
        if(NumOfRow > 1) {
            var container = document.getElementById ("msgPanel");
            var message = "The height with padding and border onClick event: " + container.offsetHeight + "px.\n";
            alert(message);
            mainDiv.removeChild(newButton);
            alert("button Removed so the DIV height will be decreased");
        } else {
            alert("Please add a Dynamic Button");
        }
    }
//-->
</script>
<style>
body{
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
font-size:13px;
}
.info, .success, .warning, .error, .validation {
border: 1px solid;
margin: 10px 0px;
padding:15px 10px 15px 50px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: 10px center;
}
.info {
color: #00529B;
background-color: #BDE5F8;
height: 460px;
width: 200px;
background-image: url('info.png');
}
.success {
color: #4F8A10;
background-color: #DFF2BF;
background-image:url('success.png');
}
.warning {
color: #9F6000;
background-color: #FEEFB3;
background-image: url('warning.png');
}
.error {
color: #D8000C;
background-color: #FFBABA;
background-image: url('error.png');
}
</style>
</HEAD>

<BODY>
 <div class="info" id="msgPanel" onresize="getParentDivHeight()" >Info message

    <div class="success">Successful operation message</div>

    <div class="warning">Warning message</div>

    <div class="error">Error message</div>

    <div id="Container1" >

    </div>

</div>
<input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="AddButton" onclick="AddNewItems()" />
</br>
</br>
<input type="button" id="btnSubmit1" value="RemoveButton" onclick="RemoveNewItems()" />
</br>
</br>
<input type="button" id="btnSubmit2" value="ShowDIVHeight" onclick="getParentDivHeight()" />
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally, the size of an div is not resized by itself. It is resized due to

- a window resize
- you add elements to it

In the 1st case you can bind using jQuery [resize()](http://api.jquery.com/resize/). In the 2nd case you will have to invoke that event yourself, from the place where you add elements to the div (the resize event is not passed to the div you are listening on).